# Calculating Grading/Land levelling volume using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I have recently been given a task from my professor to calculate Grading/land levelling volume of an airport using ArcGIS (cut/fill volume of the land). However, this is the first time for me to approach this programme so there are a few problems. Also, I have looked around on the Internet to seek for the answers but they did not seem to be applicable in my case.

**This is a brief introduction of my case:**

- I have been given an image containing contours (Nothing more than contour and it is an image, TIF file in specific).
- What I need to do is to calculate the volume of lands that need to be cut or filled in order to create a flat surface for an airport.

**And then my approach:**

- Georeferencing: I used another programme to give the image some coordinates and made it be able to be opened in ArcGIS.
- Digitising: I created a shapefile, digitised the map by sketching following the contours, created raster and TIN.
- Calculating: There are two ways that I found on the Internet: Using Cut/Fill or Surface volume.

**Problems:**

- ArcGIS provides a tool to calculate the difference between a surface and a polygon. However, the flat surface that I need to level to has inclination, which means the elevation in the polygon changes in different points. The same problem happens when using Surface volume to calculate the volume Above/Below an elevation.

**My questions are:**

- Is it possible to do the grading/levelling that I described above?
- Am I going in the right way in calculating the volume?
- If yes, please show me what I have to do or what I have done wrongly so I can learn from my mistake.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.